# Not able to click on button in ReactJS Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with box now I want to toggle this box when user click on button but box should be hide when user click on outside of button. What is wrong with this code?

I think we can resolve it with `stopPropagation()` but not able to understand how to use it do you have any idea?

My Code:-

```js
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

 return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}></button>
        {show && (
        <>
          <div style={{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute"}} onClick={()=> setShow(false)}></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
        </>) 
        }
      </div>
      );

export default App;
```

ThankYou for your efforts!

Comment: Where setShow(false) define that div using for outside...

Comment: You didn't explain the problem clearly, I'm afraid. You can't click on button, or you can't click on the box? Or you can click but it doesn't work?

Comment: actually button click is not working thats the problem...

Comment: I don't see any issue check this https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sun-j8pii

Comment: I also created a codesandbox, no issue. You can't see the box because it has no content probably. Also I would recommend using `setShow(show => !show)` instead of `setShow(!show)`. It is safer :)

Comment: Did you notice you are missing a closing `}` after the `return`? Once you fix that, it should work (see: https://jsfiddle.net/h10cpz2e/)

Comment: I guess your issue is *"but box should be hide when user click on outside of button."* where you probably mean "when the user clicks outside the box". You current box closes no matter where the user clicks (with the box open), since the `<div>` that you use to detect if a user clicks outside the box (with `position: absolute`) is placed in front of the box instead of behind it. Therefore a "click in the box" is really just a click inside the absolute div. You can use the `z-index` property to adjust the stack and place your box above the absolute div.

Answer (score 0):

If i run the code myself i can see that the element actually renders on click and the "show" value actually changes.

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(show)
  }, [show])
  return (
       <div>
         <button className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}> test </button>
         {show && (
         <>
           <div style={{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute"}} onClick={()=> setShow(false)}>elemnt to show</div>
           <div className="box"></div>
         </>) 
         }
       </div>
       );
}

export default App;
```

I just added a useEffect hook to log the show on its change and added some content to the div that is being rendered. I cant reproduce your error.

Comment: All help is appreciated but this answer seems more appropriate as a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
      
     
   function mouseOver(){
      setShow(true);
     
   } 
   function mouseOut(){
     
     setShow(flase);
     
   }
    
   
     return (
          <div>
            <button className="btn"onmouseover="mouseOver()"  onmouseout="mouseOut()"        ></button>
            {show && (
            <>
              <div style={ show ?{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute"}:{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute", display: "none" }} ></div>
              <div className="box"></div>
            </>) 
            }
          </div>
          );
    
export default App;
```

On `mouseOut()` The `Show` Sets To `false` which changes the style and `display` sets to `none` On `mouseOver` The `Show` sets to `true`which change style and `display` to `none`.    `show ?{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute"}:{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute", display: "none" }}` changes the style when there is a change in `show` State. on mouseOut and mouseOver The `show` value changes so styles also changes.In same way you can Toggle `OnClick` event